# Image trace in Illustrator doesn't work correctly with logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I am trying to trace the below image (jpg).

But it isn't coming out right at all.

Thanks!

---

Original Image:

[image]

Traced Image:

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Comment: The image is too low resolution for tracing. Recreate it instead. It's only some type. Should be easy enough.

Comment: You expect too much. You maybe can easily imagine the wanted result, but the tracing utility in Illustrator doesn't have a slightest idea of it. Tracing utility cannot imagine "this is a letter" or "that's another, but extruded" etc. The starting point of a successful tracing is an image which at least doesn't look blurry. If you can imagine the wanted result, draw it!

Comment: Why would one attempt to trace that when it's easily reconstructed? It's like trying to use a sledgehammer to repair a set of eye glasses... never gonna work. The original image is **way** too small to be traced, regardless of what it actually contains. Tracing is more akin to a Fax Machine (if you remember those) when it comes to replicating the original, not a 1:1 reconstruction.

Comment: @Scott Ok, thanks everyone. I originally had tried to recreate it, but the font was wrong. I managed to get a copy so I'll try it again.

Comment: If it's *your* logo, then you *can* change the font `:)`  It's simply a sans serif with a sharp A N and V. The rest of the letters are rather nondescript and could be any of hundreds of sans serif fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not find the original font or a better resolution file, try to recreate the font from scratch. It looks pretty simple.

Another option is finding a similar font. Focus on the A, V and D.

The truth is that in this case, I would charge the client a special fee to recreate the logo and prepare a basic identity manual so this does not happen again.

Comment: Thanks for answering but um... I am the client . I think [Trend Sans Four](http://font2s.com/fonts/50990/trend_sans_four.html) is the font used for the T and the TalinTheDev. Even if its not exact, I think its close enough for me. P.S. I used a logo generator (Tailor Brands) that's why I don't know the font.

Comment: @TalinTheDev That's **not** the font or even close to it (Look at the A) `:)` But it is your logo. You don't need a font with a built in shadow. You can simply copy the type and create your own shadow for it.

Comment: **Definitely** not Trend Sans in the logo. My first thought was [Brandon Text](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hvdfonts/brandon-text/bold/), which is at least very close. I’m not sure it’s exactly it (the crossbar on the H looks slightly lower in the logo), but it’s definitely closer than Trend Sans.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do you know a free alternative (free license)?

Comment: @TalinTheDev Not that I can think of off the top of my head, but the uppercase style is fairly basic and common, so I’m sure there are some decent matches available.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would also like the background too. Like the big t has the shadow, im pretty sure that is part of the font like trend sans... Any ideas?

Comment: @TalinTheDev No, that’s probably not part of the font. Very easy to do, just make a copy of the text in the back, give it the right colour and move it down and to the right a bit (once for the white border-ish effect, once for the light-grey shadow).